# Indefenite Integral requiring substitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone please help me find a useful substitution for the following integral:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x})^2}dx$$
I tried letting $ u = \sqrt{x} $ But I couldn't proceed. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $1+\sqrt x=u$ gives you
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=2du.$$
So,
$$\int\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}}=\int\frac{1}{u^2}\cdot \color{red}{2du}.$$

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly a workable solution, as you can absorb the factor of $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator when you write $du$, but you may as well take care of the constant in the parenthetical quantity and substitute

$$u = 1 + \sqrt{x},$$

so that $du = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}dx$, and your integral becomes

$$2 \int \frac{du}{u^2}.$$