# How many paths of length $n$ on a cycle of length $k$ that terminate at the start vertex?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a cycle of even length $k$ with vertices $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ ($k=4$ is a square) and a start vertex $v_1$, how many paths of length $n$ that terminate in $v_1$ exist?

I started by trying to model the counting argument with distance from $v_1$ as $\delta(v_i)$ so we have

$\delta(v_1) = 0$

$\delta(v_2) = \delta(v_k) = 1$

$\delta(v_3) = \delta(v_{k-1}) = 2$

$\dots$

$\delta(v_{\frac{k}{2}+1})= \delta(v_{\frac{k}{2}-1})=\frac{k}{2}-2$

$\delta(v_{\frac{k}{2}}) = \frac{k}{2} - 1$

Now, for every vertex except $v_0$ and $v_{\frac{k}{2}}$ we either increase the distance or decrease it.

From $v_0$ we can only increase, and from $v_{\frac{k}{2}}$ we can only decrease.

From here on I'm quite stuck, it might not be the way but couldn't see a better way. How can we calculate this? I do see from this argument that for odd $n$ there are no such paths since the distance increased can't be the same as the distance decreased, but couldn't go much further.

Just to make it clear, $v_1$ is connected to $v_2$ and $v_k$, $v_2$ is connected to $v_1$ and $v_3$ and so on... $v_{k-1}$ is connected to $v_{k-2}$ and $v_k$ and $v_k$ is connected to $v_{k-1}$ and $v_1$ i.e., the vertices are ordered clockwise (or anti clockwise - doesn't matter).

Comment: This is how you could continue with your now-deleted question: [Indefinite Integral requiring substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938862).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

A good way to analyse this problem is to consider a path of length $n$ as a sequence of clockwise and anti-clockwise moves:  CAACAC ...

Then you are looking for the number of strings of length $n$ for which the number of As and Cs differ by a multiple of $k$.

**Example $n=10,k=4$**

The number of As in the string of length 10 is either 1,3,5,7 or 9. So you need

$\begin{pmatrix}10\\1\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}10\\3\\\end{pmatrix}+...+\begin{pmatrix}10\\9\\\end{pmatrix}$.